# Patching a maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-14

I'm attempting to work through a problem I'm having between PostgreSQL JDBC and Hibernate in my project.

I am basically in a debug cycle, what is the fastest way I can "patch" the driver/hibernate? to see if my patches work for my use case and thus might be valuable for submission.

(in a Dynamic language I could just edit the file...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find sources to those libraries:

- https://github.com/hibernate
- https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Then you can submit a patch:

1. Dowanload sources.
2. Modify them.
3. Build SNAPSHOT version.
4. Change dependency version in your project to your SNAPSHOT version.
5. Submit a patch/pull request to project maintainer.
6. Wait till it will be released and until then use SNAPSHOT version.

Alternatively you can fork project. If you decide to I recommend to use different groupId than original project. But you would need to maintain your fork (bugfixes, updates) yourself.

But I would recommend instead doing all of that to try resolving/working around issue on your side. It may be more tricky or eventually impossible, if you stumbled upon a bug in one of those libraries. But you may post what was your actual problem on stackoverflow and see if someone else can figure something out ;)

BTW. If you found bug in one of those libraries you can submit it to

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa
- http://www.postgresql.org/list/group/5/

Comment: heh, I've been posting, working on resolving getting **native** uuid working with postgres/h2, currently it's *not possible* you could get postgres OR h2, but not both, and I have actively open bugs.

Comment: sadly, your process is what I was afraid of, there's no way to hot test the patches. Hoping that whatever Jigsaw is doing fixes this by removing Jars.

Comment: @xenoterracide Isn't it possible by extending H2 an PostgreSQL dialects (`getSqlTypeDescriptorOverride`) to support `UUID` type and implementing own `DialectResolver`? (I haven't tested that idea)

Comment: @NiematojaTomasz I should clarify, it isn't *reasonably* possible, realistically it shouldn't take more than a few JPA/Hibernate annotations on a UUID field on an entity. I think I've actually found an easier way, I know it works for H2 and Hibernate, hopefully it works sanely for other database types.